# How to inner join calendar table with 2 more tables in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, calendar

I have 2 tables that I have to inner join in PHP MySQL but I can't really understand the syntax on inner join SQL syntax. This are the structure of the 2 tables:

```
attendance = EmpID, Date, TimeIn, LunchOut, LunchIn, TimeOut
actualot = EmpID, Date, TimeIn, TimeOut, Overtime
```

I need to join them in calendar table so that the missing dates will be seen also,
this is my expected result:

```
result = Date, TimeIn, LunchOut, LunchIn, TimeOut, Overtime
```

Where date will be taken from calendar that should be equals to date of attendance with a given range like 2015-08-01 to 2015-08-30 and the Overtime is euqal to the id of attendance while the attendance is eual to the id of a given user id like 01450015. Note that i put each a auto increment primary key and the only related to each of them was the empid that is not a unique or primary key.

Comment: You will need an outer join for the Calendar table which you would join to the Attendance table.  You could also use an outer join between Attendance and ActualOT.

Comment: Thank you for the response but I am weak in join statements. Can you give at least a simple syntax to accomplish that and also does outer join is the only option?

Comment: @NewbieN What part of JOINs is not clear to you?

Comment: every kind of joins. Thank you in advance

Comment: Hey why I was donwvoted? There's no even an explanation why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example based on having a Calendar table:

```
SELECT C.Date, <additional columns>
FROM Calendar C LEFT OUTER JOIN
Attendance D ON C.Date = D.Date LEFT OUTER JOIN
ActualOT A ON D.EmpID = A.EmpID
```

Comment: Thanks I will try your code and check if there will be errors, thanks in advance

Comment: I didn't gain any errors but I am missing some results like  the missing date gaps in date.

Comment: I just notice that the value for actualot was not showing after I used inner join.